# How would this spec pass

Tags: ruby, rspec

I ran into a github spec that was failing and as I am learning how to write specs, I fixed two of them that were failing apart for the last one in with a comment #THIS ONE IS STILL FAILING. How would one make it pass?

```
class Team
  attr_reader :players
  def initialize
    @players = Players.new
  end
end

class Players
  def initialize
    @players = ["","Some Player",""]
  end
  def size
    @players.size
  end
  def include? player
    raise "player must be a string" unless player.is_a?(String)
    @players.include? player
  end
end

describe "A new team" do

  before(:each) do
    @team = Team.new
  end

  it "should have 3 players (failing example)" do
    @team.should have(3).players
  end

  it "should include some player (failing example)" do
    @team.players.should include("Some Player")
  end

  #THIS ONE IS STILL FAILING
  it "should include 5 (failing example)" do
    @team.players.should include(5)
  end

  it "should have no players"

end
```

Comment: Simply write `return true if player == 5` :P What is the expected outcome? What does it mean for a list of players, identified by strings, to include the number 5? Or should that example actually say `it "should raise for the number 5"`?

Comment: I got it from here: https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/examples/failing/team_spec.rb. The author didn't explain what it does.

Comment: These tests are designed to help you understand what a failure in rspec means. Look at what message you get from rspec when this test fails. What does this tell you about the test and the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the aim is to modify the spec, not to modify the code to pass the spec.

In this case, we don't actually expect `@team.players` to include 5; rather, we expect it to raise an exception when asked whether it includes a non-string. This can be written as follows:

```
  it "should raise an exception when asked whether it includes an integer" do
    expect {
      @team.players.should include(5)
    }.to raise_exception
  end
```

For a check on the exception type and message, use `raise_exception(RuntimeError, "player must be a string")`.

You should probably modify the descriptions of the other two specs similarly, since they no longer fail.

Comment: Thank you. I was geared more towards modifying the code because I thought that the goal of RSPEC is writing tests first and then writing code to make those tests pass. After reading the code carefully, you beat me to the solution. **When you "You should probably modify the descriptions of the other two specs similarly, since they no longer fail.", what do you mean?**

Comment: It still says "(failing example)" in both of them, even though they no longer fail.

Comment: Indeed test-first programming is often recommended, so it seems that this example does have it backwards. However, if the example expected you to write tests first, there wouldn't be any base code to begin with :)

Comment: No, the aim is neither to modify the spec nor the code. The aim is to run them, so that you can see what the output of a failed spec looks like. Plus, they are also used by RSpec's own testsuite to verify that the output for failed specs stays the same between different releases of RSpec. It's spelled out quite clearly in the [`README.txt`](https://GitHub.Com/DChelimsky/RSpec/blob/master/examples/failing/README.txt) for that directory.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I failed to look at the bigger picture. Thanks for clearing that up!